# How to pass a variable in Devise sign_up link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I pass a variable to my sign_up controller using Devise? I want to add the user chosen plan to the database on registration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your routes.rb

```
match 'register' => redirect('/users/sign_up?plan=pro')
```

OR

```
match 'register/:plan' => redirect('/users/sign_up/{%plan}')
```

And create the matching controllers.

Get more routes info from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Alternatively, this can also be used https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages